# Modifying another checkmark, or adding another one?

Tags: xetex, symbols, unicode

I should explain beforehand, that I use XeLaTeX, so I have access to all kinds of fonts, and Unicode support.

Now, I'm using the "BALLOT BOX" (U+2610) and "BALLOT BOX WITH CHECK" (U+2611) quite often for attendance protocols.

Now, I'd like to add another character in the likes of that, but with a little "e" or "E" inside the ballot box. This is what I plan to use for "excused". I'd much rather mix the "BALLOT BOX" character with a smaller "E", rather than constructing a new shape as SVG or something, so it'll be no problem when changing to a different font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, maybe you may just use a `\fbox`, and you can change the spacing and font size:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{relsize}

\begin{document}

A\raisebox{0.1em}{\smaller\fboxsep0.1em\fbox{E}}B

\end{document}
```

You don't need a Unicode font for this.

---

And of course, you can mix the two symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial Unicode MS}
\usepackage{relsize}
\begin{document}

A\ooalign{\symbol{"2610}\cr\hfil\smaller[2]\raisebox{0.1em}{E}\hfil\cr}B\symbol{"2611}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank! I've used your second solution like that:
`\newcommand{\e}{
    {\dejavusans \hspace{-.6em} \ooalign{☐\cr \tiny \hfil \hspace{0.01em} \raisebox{0.3em}{E} \hfil \cr}}
}`

Answer (score 4):

The following example defines `\ballot` that takes an argument that is put into the empty ballot box both horizontally and vertically centered. If necessary the contents is scaled down to fit the ballot box.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newdimen\BallotDimen
\newsavebox\BallotBoxEmpty
\newsavebox\BallotBoxChar
\newcommand*{\ballot}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}%
    \sbox\BallotBoxEmpty{^^^^2610}%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{.175\wd\BallotBoxEmpty}%
    \BallotDimen=\dimexpr\wd\BallotBoxEmpty-2\fboxsep\relax
    \sbox\BallotBoxChar{#1}%
    \ifdim\wd\BallotBoxChar>\BallotDimen
      \sbox\BallotBoxChar{\resizebox{\BallotDimen}{!}{\usebox\BallotBoxChar}}%
    \fi
    \ifdim\dp\BallotBoxChar>0pt %
      \sbox\BallotBoxChar{\raisebox{\dp\BallotBoxChar}{\usebox\BallotBoxChar}}%
    \fi
    \ifdim\ht\BallotBoxChar>\BallotDimen
      \sbox\BallotBoxChar{\resizebox{!}{\BallotDimen}{\usebox\BallotBoxChar}}%
    \fi
    \ooalign{%
      \usebox\BallotBoxEmpty\cr
      \hfil
      \raisebox{.5\dimexpr\ht\BallotBoxEmpty-\ht\BallotBoxChar}%
               {\usebox\BallotBoxChar}%
      \hfil
    }%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\fontspec{FreeSerif.otf}
^^^^2610^^^^2611^^^^2612\ballot{E}\ballot{e}\ballot{g}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]